# StatusBarControl Binding MVVM Pattern in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

I am trying to make winform in to MVVM pattern.

I am using

```
public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings { get; }
```

in `System.Windows.Forms` and

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
```

in `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel`

For normal control like radion button or button it is very easy for binding view and model together.

```
_control.radioButton.DataBindings.Add(
  "Checked", 
  model, 
  nameof(model.function_name), 
  true, 
  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

I have some problem with Binding `System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar.StatusBarPanel.Text`.

I can not bind `Text` in  `StatusBarPanelCollection` and `StatusBarPanelCollection`  is in `StatusBar` control.

```
public class viewmodel : ObservableObject
{
    private view _viewControl;
    private Model _model;

    public MainFormControlState(Model model, View view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _model = model;
   
    }

    private void ViewModelBindings()
    {
     _view.radioButton.DataBindings.Add("Checked", model, nameof(model.function_name), true, 
     DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        veiw.statusBar.Panels[1].Text.DataBindings() // This binding does not work because Text is string;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `veiw.statusBar.Panels[1].Text` (+ a typo) and how does it relate to this: `System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar.StatusBarPanel.Text`? Are you trying to set the `Text` of a Panel? Did you actually use a `StatusBar` Control? Are you porting an ancient Project? Or is it a Custom Control?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar.StatusBarPanel.Text from model 
 That is reason i am trying to Databind. And StatusBar is control from Windows.Forms. and StatusBar is standard control  in Winform

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the documentation very clearly [tells you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusbarpanel?view=netframework-4.8):

> This class is not available in .NET 5 and later versions. Use the StatusStrip control instead, which replaces and extends the StatusBar control.

And indeed, if you look at `StatusStrip`, [it does have a `DataBindings` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0).

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar has DataBindings property. And i can bind to StatusBar. But What i want to is how to access/update panels and panel text after Databinding. so i can update the panel and panel text. And I have to use .Net 4 for project reason